# Windows SFTP server has intermittent slow login issues

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, sftp

I have installed SFTP on 3 separate windows server with the same config. One of them is having intermittent slow logins. About a minute to log in but sometimes it logs in within seconds.

I have changed the SSHconfig to not use DNS `UseDNS no`

I have done a debug ssh -v user@localhost and it looks like its getting stuck on below when it takes a while to log in.

`debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_9.2`

Is anyone able to help me out. Been stuck with this for weeks now. :(